# Why __add__ magic method does not work?

Tags: python

I want to change the ADD python Magic Method (I mean, **__add__**) for add two numbers (Code 1). When I run the code, the output is equal to **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object** in Pycharm IDE. But after changing the code (Code 2), then the new code worked properly. Why does the Code 1 not work?

Code 1 (Wrong):

```
class Number(int):  
    def __add__(self, other):  
        return self + other
print(Number(5) + 3)
```

Code 2 (Correct):

```
class Number(int):  
    def __add__(self, other):  
        return self - (-other)  
print(Number(5) + 3)
```

Comment: Try: `return self.__int__() + other` or: override `__radd__`  instead of overriding `__add__`

Comment: So to add your object to another object, you... add the two objects? And you add the two objects by... adding the two objects? And you do that by... what did you think defining your method as `return self + other` was going to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because `self` is a `Number`, so `self + other` calls `self.__add__(other)`, which does `self + other`, which calls...

The fix is to turn `self` into something that isn't a `Number` before adding.

```
return int(self) + other
```

Comment: Do you know, Why "return self - (-other)"  code worked correctly?

Comment: @RezaHarasani: Subtraction invokes `__sub__()`.